# Optimize duplicated but negated subquery

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, optimization, subquery

I have what I call a 'Hamlet' query in the form:

```
select * from stuff a
left join otherStuff b on (a.x=b.x) -- lots of joins ommited
where
 (b.ToBe = 1 and a.Being in (select Being from stuffThatIs where stuffThatIs.Name = b.Name)
 or
 (b.ToBe <> 1 and a.Being not in (select Being from stuffThatIs where stuffThatIs.Name = b.Name)
```

The most-nested queries being identical, so I thought the database would reuse the result instead of doing 2 queries.

But in the execution plan the query shows twice with the same cost of 19%.

Can this be optimized manually? Or a hint added?
I'd prefer a portable solution instead of a maximum perf one.

There are indexes on all named columns, sometimes even unique. The example is simplified, the whole `where` clause is in a join condition itself etc. So please optimize just the pattern, not the whole query.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Have you tried using a CTE (common table expression)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query would be better?
We would check stuffThatIs for every row, and then validate if

1. `ToBe=1` and `there is a.Being in stuffThatIs`  *OR*
2. `ToBe<>1` and `there isn't a.Being in stuffThatIs`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM someStuff a
LEFT JOIN otherStuff b ON (a.x = b.x)
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT 1 [is_inside]
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *
               FROM stuffThatIs x
               WHERE x.Name = b.Name  
                 AND x.Being = b.Being) -- instead of "...a.Being in (select Being..."
) x
WHERE ((a.ToBe = 1 AND x.is_inside IS NOT NULL)
    OR (a.ToBe <> 1 AND x.is_inside IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work... unless you expect multiple duplicates from stuffthatis (in which case, try joining to a subquery of SELECT DISTINCT).

```
select A.*, B.*
from stuff a
left join otherStuff b on (a.x=b.x) -- lots of joins ommited
LEFT JOIN stuffthatis c on b.name = c.name

where
 (b.ToBe = 1 and a.Being = C.being)
 or
 (b.ToBe <> 1 and C.name is null)
```